# What makes object from react state is undefined but accessible in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encounter weird issue... say I have a method like:

```
someMethod = () => {
    console.log({state:this.state}) // always giving correct object
    console.log({selectedIndex:this.state.selectedIndex}) // always giving correct value
    let {selectedIndex} = this.state // sometime not giving error, sometime giving error "undefined is not object (evaluating '_state3.selectedIndex')"
}
```

When I am going to run `someMethod` multiple times,

sometimes selectedIndex is accessible and sometimes is undefined and giving error "undefined is not object (evaluating '_state3.selectedIndex')"..

The weird part is that console always giving correct value even when selectedIndex is undefined...

what makes an object from reacting state is undefined but accessible in console..??

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably happening because `selectedIndex` does not exist in `this.state` at the time of calling `someMethod`

Answer (score 0):

this is my mistake... and i learn something...

actually,, i have other dict inside react state say `otherDict`..

```
state = {
  selectedIndex: 0,
  otherDict: 'someValue'
}
```

after some process i accidentally making `otherDict` undefined with

```
this.setState({otherDict:undefined})
```

and when im going to distruct `this.state` with

```
let {selectedIndex, otherDict} = this.state
```

babel cannot distructing `undefined` variable and that's why babel throw error `undefined`